# ADF ViewObject- Dynamically change where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

```
      <ViewObject name ="emp" selectList="select * from employees" Where= "empno=?" />
```

inside my action class, I'd like to change the where condition to `sal=10` leading to `select * from employees Where sal =10`.

I don't want the `empno` column in the `WHERE` clause.

the `vo.setwhereclause(null)` isn't clearing the `empno =?`. It's appending `sal=?` to existing where clause.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A simplest way to do this is don't include where param in your view object query but use your where param dynamically through back bean or managed bean function code like,

```
ViewObject vo1 = applicationmoduleobject.findViewObject("viewobjectname");
vo.setWhereClause(" CREATED_BY = userId and ASSIGNMENT_ID = assignId"); 
long count = vo.getEstimatedRowCount();
```

Here, in your view object use simple "select * query" and dynamically add where clause using bean method and execute your view object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you solve it:

```
<ViewObject name="emp" selectList="select * from employees" Where="sal=10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By default ViewObject augments where clause to existing sql code.
To avoid this trouble you should use ViewObject.FULLSQL_MODE_AUGMENTATION property. Example:

```
ViewObject vo = getViewObject();
vo.setFullSqlMode(voi.FULLSQL_MODE_AUGMENTATION);
vo.setWhereClause("sal=:sal"); //or use setSql()
vo.setWhereClauseParam("sal",10.00);
vo.clearCache();
vo.executeQuery();
```

Comment: The new where clause got appended to the initial query. So now my sql is select * from employees where empno=? and sal =10. Is there anyway I can avoid this?

Comment: Ok, then try to change whole sql using setQuery(String newSql)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic clauses can only be appended to VO query. If there is a need to remove any clause from VO query, there is no method present for that, so the below code can be used as a workaround:

```
System.out.println("Original query: " +sanctVo.getQuery());

sanctVo.setQuery("select * from employees where sal = :1");
sanctVo.setWhereClauseParam(0, 10);
System.out.println("New query: " +sanctVo.getQuery());
sanctVo.executeQuery();
```

Comment: there are no method setQuery